# Sort manually added controls inside ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listbox, controls

I have a ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="LbFrequentColumnItems" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="0"></ListBox>
```

I am adding many imagebuttons to the above listbox as shown below:

```
ImageButton b = new ImageButton();
b.Content = d.DisplayName;              
b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(OptionalColumnItems_Click);
LbFrequentColumnItems.Items.Add(b);
```

On a button click I need to show all my Imagebuttons in sorted order by its content.

I can do it by copying all in list and then sorting and again adding buttons.

But is there any direct way or any method on listbox to perform it?

I tried something as below, but it is not working as I don't have any property bindings:

```
LbFrequentColumnItems
    .Items
    .SortDescriptions
    .Add(
         new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("",
            System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just sort them by `Content` property:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LbFrequentColumnItems
        .Items
        .SortDescriptions
        .Add(new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

It won't throw `InvalidOperationException` because `System.String` implements the `IComparable` interface, that is not implemented by `(Image)Button`.

Demo:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var names = Enumerable
        .Range(1, 10)
        .OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Select(i =>
            i.ToString());

    foreach (var button in this.CreateNewButtons(names))
    {
        LbFrequentColumnItems.Items.Add(button);                
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Button> CreateNewButtons(IEnumerable<String> names)
{
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Content = name;
        b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(OptionalColumnItems_Click);

        yield return b;
    }
}

private void OptionalColumnItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Xaml:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Name="LbFrequentColumnItems" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="0"></ListBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Reorder" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

**P.S.:** In the same way you can set Button DataContext property to some specific dataobject implementing `IComparable` and sort by `DataContext` - `new SortDescription("DataContext", ListSortDirection.Ascending)`

**P.S.1:** While manually adding buttons is not prohibited, it is nonetheless much better to use advanced databinding and templating capabilites of WPF. They, after some initial investment, will make the application much easier to develop and modify.